# SQL: Subquery filter by parent field

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following SQL query, that I can't get to work.

## Data Schema

```
| Timestamp                | Status   | Amount |
|--------------------------|----------|--------|
| 2016-03-23T08:03:34.204Z | Approved |   100  |
| 2016-03-23T16:00:06.755Z | Declined |   450  |
| 2016-03-30T10:18:43.846Z | Approved | 50010  |
```

## Desired Output

```
| Date       | Approved Count | Declined Count |
|------------|----------------|----------------|
| 2016-03-23 | 1              | 1              |
| 2016-03-30 | 1              | 0              |
```

## What I've tried

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS Date,

  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM db.transactions
   WHERE status='Approved'
     AND DATE(timestamp)=Date) AS Approved,

  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM db.transactions
   WHERE status='Declined') AS Declined
FROM db.transactions a
GROUP BY Date;
```

.. which fails with the error message:

> An error occurred with Amazon Redshift. column "date" does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is from trying to use a column alias defined in your `SELECT` clause in your `GROUP BY` clause, the alias is not available because `GROUP BY` is actually processed before `SELECT`. You could get rid of the error by using `GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)`, but this can be done much more efficiently with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS Date
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN status='Approved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Approved
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN status='Declined' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Declined
FROM db.transactions
GROUP BY  DATE(timestamp)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! ✋

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT DATE(timestamp),

  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM db.transactions
   WHERE status='Approved'
     AND DATE(timestamp) AS Approved,

  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM db.transactions
   WHERE status='Declined') AS Declined
FROM db.transactions GROUP BY Date;
```

Comment: `An error occurred with Amazon Redshift. syntax error at or near "AS"`